# How to bind Background color to another IsSelected Background

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, background, selected

I want to bind the selected Background color of MyDataGrid to another IsSelected Background color so they share the same color. I'm thinking it can be done something like below. How can I do it?

```
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=OtherDataGrid, Path=??Background??" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to share the background is to use a `StaticResource`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a brush in resources and refer that in both the data grids.

Like:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource selectedCellBackground}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to declare a notify property in the view model and bind both colors to it.